# First cohomology of the space of long knots in ℝ⁴

Tags: knot-theory, loop-spaces, spectral-sequences, differential-topology

Let's consider the space of long knots in $\mathbb R^n$, $n>3$. I know that there are many results (Vassiliev, Turchin, Sinha, Kontsevich) about different expressions of cohomology of this space. I think the last result is about convergency in $E^1$ term ([Lambrechts, Turchin, and Volić - The rational homology of spaces of long knots in codimension $> 2$](http://palmer.wellesley.edu/%7Eivolic/pdf/Papers/VassilievCollapseFinal-G%26T.pdf)).

But my question is about what these cohomologies are precise. So, is it true that $H^1(\text{long knots in $\mathbb R^4$})=0$?

Does there exist some table with $H^i(\text{space of long knots in $\mathbb R^j$})$ at least for small $i$, $j$?

Comment: Is $H^∗$ the usual cohomology? Can't you compute everything applying Alexander duality (or something similar) to the pair $(S^j,S^1)$? Or maybe I'm just misinterpreting everything...

Comment: @Marco: he's talking about the space of *all* embeddings, as a function space.  I think you might be interpreting the space as the knot complement. 

Comment: @Marco: I've modified question for clarity (added word "space"). 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Long knots in $\mathbb R^4$ form a simply-connected space.   I pointed this out in my survey paper [A Family of Embedding Spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605069).  The primary tool used to prove it is what's called the *embedding calculus* due to Goodwillie, Klein and Weiss.

Let $\mathcal K_{n,j}$ denote the space of long embeddings of $\mathbb R^j$ into $\mathbb R^n$. The same survey paper above shows that $\mathcal K_{n,j}$ is $(2n-3j-4)$-connected, and the $(2n-3j-3)$-rd homotopy group is computed. It turns out to be either $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z_2$ depending on a parity issue, assuming $2n-3j-3 \geq 0$.

When $2n-3j-3<0$ there are a few cases where some of these homotopy groups are computed, due to Haefliger and Kervaire.   When $2n-3j-3>0$ many of the rational groups have been computed by Victor Turchin in [On the other side of the bialgebra of chord diagrams](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411436).   But very few integral homotopy or homology groups have been computed as of yet.

Comment: It seems that it is possible to prove simply-connectedness for knots in simply-connected four-dimensional manifold just by geometric observations, so I've asked for to be convinced that it is true.  Thank you!

Comment: I wonder, perhaps $Emb(S^1,\mathbb CP^2)$ is not simply connected?  A loop in this embedding space could sweep-out the generator of $H_2 \mathbb CP^2 \simeq \mathbb Z$.  Perhaps that's non-trivial?